# Find and delete records that are close in time

Tags: sqlite

I am logging temperature to an sqlite db and the sensor sends a burst of ~6 readings every ~40 seconds in order to be sure one is received. By adding the Unique property to the date field, I have eliminated most of the dups. However, sometimes the clock ticks 1 second during the burst such that I have records that are ~1 second apart. I would like to keep only one reading for each 40 sec burst. How can I find (and therefore delete) these records?

```
insDate             id  temp    humidity 
2019-07-08 11:34:07 176 41.36   70.0 
2019-07-08 11:34:46 176 41.36   70.0 
2019-07-08 11:34:47 176 41.36   70.0 
2019-07-08 11:35:26 176 41.36   70.0 
2019-07-08 11:36:05 176 41.36   70.0 
2019-07-08 11:36:06 176 41.36   70.0 
2019-07-08 11:36:45 176 41.36   70.0
```

Comment: Post sample data and expected results, because this *for each 40 sec period* is not clear.

Comment: It sends 6 copies of each timestamp's readings?

Comment: It sounds like the 6 readings are sent in bursts and not spread throughout the 40-second time window, correct?  Will the temperature reading be the same value, or could the temperature reading be different for the "6 readings"?  (There is a difference between "6 readings" and "6 transmissions of the same reading".)  If the temperature value can change within the burst of 6 values sent, are you also interested in keeping the changed temperature value, or are you still only interested in a single reading per 6 seconds?

Comment: insDate                          id temp humidity
2019-07-08 11:34:07 176 41.36 70.0
2019-07-08 11:34:46 176 41.36 70.0
2019-07-08 11:34:47 176 41.36 70.0
2019-07-08 11:35:26 176 41.36 70.0
2019-07-08 11:36:05 176 41.36 70.0
2019-07-08 11:36:06 176 41.36 70.0
2019-07-08 11:36:45 176 41.36 70.0

Comment: The sensor sends 6 readings each time it reports. Most of the dups are eliminated by having the UNIQUE property on insDate field. However some get through because the timestamp differs by a second or 2.

Comment: I am only interest in keeping one reading from the "burst". Keeping more, messes up the average, etc.

Comment: Could you not grab the first timestamp from a burst and use that for all readings?  Then your `unique` constrain will automatically eliminate all duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each adjacent block of 40 seconds would always have exactly 6 readings, then there isn't necessarily a start and end to a group of 6 readings.  We can try aggregating the readings by blocks of 40 seconds, and then just taking the `MIN` reading for each block:

```
SELECT
    ts % 40 AS block,
    MIN(reading) AS reading
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    ts % 40
ORDER BY
    ts % 40;
```

The reason this should work is that suppose the minimum value we chose actually belongs to a "previous" block, because we guessed the boundary incorrectly.  Then, this shift would also be present in the next block, and the block after that, so it does not matter in the end.

This answer assumes that the time reading is in a column called `ts`, and it contains something like seconds since the epoch.

Comment: I can try that but I am not sure if I can trust the 40 sec. Sometimes the timestamp shows a slightly different number (always more than 20). However, there can be missing reaings that were not received or other things can interfere. Best, would be if I could compare timestamps and eliminate all but one that are within x sec. of each other

Comment: The problem is that the boundary you perceive to be there may not be there at all.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Or the modulus-40 boundary could occur between one of the 6 values, thereby grouping a "stray" reading with the previous group... and if using an aggregate like MIN(), could incorrectly record the reading as happening in the prior group.  Although the mathematical modulus is likely the key to solving this, the OP really needs to specify the conditions more precise before trying to guess at what is needed and what variation is tolerable in the readings.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  BTW, why doubt the OP as though the boundary is only "perceived".  I have worked with such data acquisition scenarios and it is not just "perceived".

Comment: I want to keep one reading from each burst of 6 (or so) readings that are close in time relative to the inter burst time of approx 40 sec.

Comment: @ihf  Please edit and improve the actual question.  Don't leave critical details as scattered comments.  That is best for any question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CPerkins If the bursts of reading are really truly random, then an approach along the lines of what I suggested might be the best we can do.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problems discussed in comments where a mathematical time window (using modulus operator) might arbitrarily cut off/split readings from the same burst, instead we can inspect neighboring records to get the time delay between successive readings.  The question details imply that readings within the same burst of records will likely occur in a very short time (within a couple seconds) compared to the delay between bursts (~40 seconds).  So to get a single reading per burst, select only the records which have a long delay to the next record, somewhere between 2 and 40 seconds... which I somewhat arbitrarily choose 10.

Luckily sqlite supports *window functions* which allow comparison of neighboring rows using basic SQL queries--no need to script anything outside SQL.

```
WITH sensorExt AS (
       SELECT *, 
              strftime('%s', insDate) AS tsec --Convert to seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00
       FROM sensor )
SELECT *
FROM -- Must use subquery in order to apply WHERE conditions to window function results
  (SELECT sensorExt.*,
         (lead(tsec) OVER (ORDER BY insDate ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING))
          - tsec as postspan -- Calculate difference between following row seconds
   FROM sensorExt
   ORDER BY sensorExt.insDate) AS sensorExt2
WHERE
   -- Only keep rows which are at end of "burst" with large delay to next record 
   -- coalesce() is called to handle/include the null value of the last record.
   coalesce(postspan, 11) > 10
```

---

*Note 1*:  I prefer to use *common table expressions* (CTE; the WITH clause) instead of subqueries when possible, but there seems to be a bug with *window functions* (i.e. OVER clause) within a CTE, so I had to revert to a subquery.  Otherwise I would have used a series of CTE tables instead of mixing the constructs.

*Note 2*:  This can also be accomplished without window functions, using standard aggregate SQL queries, but I think it would require at least a set of 3 nested subqueries just to get the difference between neighboring rows.